# Mitsubishi Outlander 2012 ES / Hearing relay click sound from the back every time I press the brake pedal?

Tags: brakes, noise, relay

I just purchased a used Mitsubishi Outlander 2012 ES with leather seats and 4WD. I never sat in one before.

Is it normal to hear a relay click at the back of the vehicle every single time I press on the brake pedal? Driving slow, fast, parked, doesn't matter, every single time I press the brake pedal, a relay clicks at the back of he vehicle.

Lights perfectly lit up when I press the brake pedal, btw. There doesn't seem to be anything wrong per se with the vehicle, except this F annoying relay click sound.

Waiting for somebody who actually owns one to tell me if theirs has this relay clicking when they brake.  (I hope not)

Comment: That must be some loud relay! Does this car have any aftermarket lighting, or is it stock?

Comment: It might be for switching lights on a trailer?  Does it have a socket for trailer lights?

Comment: It does have a hitch and it looks like an aftermarket one, because a small part of the hitch rack sticks out the back a little, doesn't look OEM to me.  But do 2012 Outlanders require non-standard relay stuff to make trailer lights work tough?  I own a trailer attached to an older Jeep and it doesn't require any relay clicking for lights to work.

Comment: I'm wondering if it's a brake switch for towing?